# Failed to create contract address on Polygon Mainnet

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, polygon

I am using openzeppelin to create token on polygon mainnet everytime I deploy my contract address I got an error

[image]

Comment: add more info please. how are u deploying it and do you have enough balance and are you connected to the correct network?

Comment: @MajdTL I have connected to Polygon Main net and I have 0.01 Matic in my balance